# glDrawArray+VBO increasing memory footprint

Tags: opengl

I am writing a Windows based OpenGL viewer application.
I am using VBO + triangle strip + glDrawArrays method to render my meshes. Every thing is perfectly working on all machines. 
In case of Windows Desktop with nVidia Quadro cards the working/peak working memory shoots when i first call glDrawArray.
While in case of laptops having nvidia mobile graphic cards the working memory or peak working memory does not shoot. Since last few days i am checking almost all forums/post/tuts about VBO memory issue. Tried all combinations of VBO like GL_STATIC_DRAW/DYNAMIC/STREAM, glMapbuffer/glunmapbuffer. But nothing stops shooting memory on my desktops.
I suspect that for VBO with ogl 1.5 i am missing some flags.
PS: I have almost 500 to 600 VBO's in my application. I am using array of structures ( i.e. v,n,c,t together in a structure). And I am not aligning my VBOs to 16k memory.
Can any one suggest me how I should go ahead to solve this issue. Any hints/pointers would be helpful.

Comment: If you're new here, be sure to inform yourself about the accept and up-vote functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually run out of memory or does your application increasingly consume memory? If not, why bother? If the OpenGL implementation keeps a working copy for itself, then this is probably for a reason. Also there's little you can do on the OpenGL side to avoid this, since it's entirely up to the driver how it manages its stuff. I think the best course of action, if you really want to keep the memory footprint low, is contacting NVidia, so that they can double check if this may be a bug in their drivers.

Comment: Thanx datenwolf....I wud ask nVidia folks. My main issue is this does not happen on all machines. And for betterment of my product i should atleast know the reason.

Comment: @user368912: OpenGL assumes an abstract model of the machinary that performs the rendering. And a driver/GPU combination is free to do whatever it takes to follow the OpenGL specification. For example OpenGL objects like textures or vertex buffer objects may require some additional copy in system memory to recreate them on the GPU in case they got deleted from GPU memory. For example the GPU may crash and the driver transparently reboots it and thus requires a full copy of the data in system RAM. Or the driver provisions for other applications accessing the GPU in parallel, swapping objects.